# How to use category in auto generated title?

Tags: entries, categories, entry

I have an entry which has a category field. I want an auto-generated title for this entry that uses the assigned category title (first category title in case of multiple categories). I am not sure what to insert in the "Title Format" field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Title Format field, try:

`{categoryFieldHandle[0].title}`